# facebook app domain

Tags: facebook

I try register my web-site on facebook.
My website *http://itmarket.issart.com/*
I try use in App Domains
*itmarket.issart.com*
*www.itmarket.issart.com*
and other and always i have error 
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a valid integration URL.

www.itmarket.issart.com must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.

Comment: have you selected an option from "how your app integrates with Facebook"? either "App on Facebook", "mobile web", "page tab" etc.

Comment: Thanks to all, i just added link of my site to site url field